# Redirecting pages when clicking on tags in posts

Tags: wordpress, tags, posts

Good afternoon, everyone.

I'm having an issue while making some posts on a WordPress website. The problem is that, when I add a tag to the post, clicking on it redirects me to a completely disconfigured page, without the correct WordPress theme layout.

Does anyone here know how I can fix this and redirect to the correct page?

Thank you in advance.

[tag1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggs4c.png)
[tag2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amCmG.png)

I tried accessing the tag option, but I can't find any settings related to changing the tag links.